# How to pass a list of anonymous object?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I've pushed most of a method functionality inside a store procedure. I'm returning a join result of 2 tables, so there is no type to collect the return data. I'm thinking of using anonymous type.

```
public static List<Anonymous Type> 
              SaveUsersToGroup(int groupId, List<int> userIds)
{


   //more here ...

   var list = new List<Anonymous Type>();
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {

      list.Add(new { Id = row["Id"].ToString(), 
                     FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString(),
                     LastName = row["LastName"].ToString()
              });
   }
}
```

Now how to create a list of anonymous object. And (most importantly) what will be the return type for this method?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why not create a type which you can project into? in place of an anonymouse type? that way you can return a list of that type

Comment: Why not use Generic? maybe you need a universal method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point about anonymous types is that they're anonymous. You're trying to name them, which doesn't make them anonymous anymore.

Either use `dynamic` (not my favorite solution) or create a class that holds `Id`, `FirstName` and `lastName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that:

> **You cannot declare** a field, a property, an event, or **the return type of a method as having an anonymous type**.
>
> [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

You can declare mathod as `IEnumerable<object>` but you'll looks type safety going this way and you'll have* to use `dynamic` to read the results.

You should create simple POCO class and return set of that class items instead of anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dynamic`, since your projection is ananymous